# Is this how I should be opening push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

When the notification is clicked on I want it to open a specific page, but for some reason it keeps crashing with the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Why is this error happening? Am I opening the page correctly?

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let notificationDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
            self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notificationDictionary)
            let text = launchOptions["aps"]!["alert"]
            print(text)
            let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Player") as UIViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = viewController

        }
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
  let text = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]
    print(text)
    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Player") as UIViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
}
```

Comment: This is not proper way to create or initiate view controller when receive notification. Instead you have to get visible view controller which are at top of stack at moment and use it to perform other action.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying.

Comment: Which page you want to open , when receive notification ?

Comment: I want to open a view controller with a storyboard id "Player"

Comment: "Player" is your firstViewController in Stack ?

Comment: No it is not the initial view controller. The initial view controller is a login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :

Find visible view controller when receive Notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let currentViewControlelr :UIViewController = topViewController(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)!;

    if(currentViewController == PlayerViewController()){

        //Implement other function according to your needs

    }else{

        //If any other view controller at top of stack, then create object of Player View controller and push to that

         let playerViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Player") as UIViewController
                 currentViewControlelr.navigationController?.pushViewController(playerViewController, animated: true)
    NSLog("UserInfo : %@",userInfo);

}
```

Helper Method to get Top ViewController which is visible at the moment

```
func topViewController(base: UIViewController? ) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)

    }
    return base
    }
```

Comment: How would I actually open the page, cause all I see is instantiating playerViewController, not actually opening it.

Comment: Code is push on player view controller using visible view controller's navigation controller.